# Calculating CPU usage on a Linux multicore machine using C

Tags: c, linux, cpu, proc

I'm working on a program that shows the percentage of every process running on a machine with Linux. The problem is that the percentage I get often differs from the one displayed by the `top` command.

I searched for many hours on the web but what I find is almost always the same formula

`100 * (stime + utime)/ (totalCPUTime - processStartTime)`.

I get the totalCPUTime summing the 7 CPU values in `/proc/stat` , while `stime`, `utime` and `processStartTime` are values taken form `/proc/<pid>/stat`.
Am I doing something wrong? 
Does the fact that I am running the program on a multicore machine affect somehow the result?

Does somone know how the top calculates this value?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what top does you should have a look in the source code :)

[top.c cvs repository](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/top.c?view=markup)

[procps Homepage](http://procps.sourceforge.net/index.html)